# Best way to create scala based command line scripts?

Tags: scala

Is the best way currently to make a scala command-line utility to use sbt-assembly and then push the .jar to the production environment and run:

```
java -classpath my.jar path.to.main.app
```

Are there other ways of doing this or this is basically the best way?

Comment: Check out Ammonite http://www.lihaoyi.com/Ammonite/

Answer (score 0):

If you look at sbt-assembly, the main class can be configured by 'mainClass in assembly' setting.

By that sbt creates a MANIFEST.MF entry pointing to the main class (see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html)

Now you can start your utility with

java -jar my.jar